# How can I automate/loop signature changes in Ableton?

Tags: midi, ableton-live, automation

I'm trying to make a loop which has one bar of 7/8 and one bar of 4/4, but I don't want to have to manually do that (ie right-clicking the Arrangement View and changing sig) to several minutes' worth of music. Should I just set the sig to 15/8 and put up with it? For instance, it seems lots of people use a master tempo track to handle tempo changes - is there some kind of signature track I could make that does this, but every run-through of a loop? Thanks in advance.

[image: The normal method of time sig changes]

Edit: I ended up just going with 15/8; couldn't find a solution. Oh well.

Comment: Do you even need the master tempo/signature to match up if you're working in the arrangement?

Comment: It's pretty important, I think, for stuff like sample warping and looping phrases. I'll edit the AND out - it gives incorrect emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

On a very personal view, I'd recommend just leaving it to 15/8 - it's just easier.

I think [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKmaMMaiHrM) might help a little, but the easiest way to do it is by right cliking on the siganure filed (it's on the right of the tempo field) and clicking 'Edit Automation'.

If I remember correctly, that will show a signature automation on the master track.

Make the loop the way you want it and then copy/paste the automation across the track.

Then again, I'm not 100% sure on this answer, and I can't open Ableton to confirm this now.

Comment: Unfortunately the only automated value is tempo - right-clicking just selects either the numerator or denominator and gives "Return to default". Oh well; 15/8 actually hasn't proven too annoying so far with sample warping so you're probably right about sticking to it. The Session View thing seems too cumbersome for composition (and especially for transferral to Arrangement). Thanks, anyway.

Comment: The problem is that it's possible to automate that tempo change in the Session View, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, and it's not really mirrored easily into Arrangement.